# Example Android app I can reuse for as the official app for a large-scale event

Tags: android, open-source, offline, calendar, maps

I want to write the official app for a large event:

- with hundreds of events spanning over several days
- in several locations (conference halls/stadiums/etc)

Features wanted:

- Calendar of events
- Map of locations *(or at least links opening GPS app)*
- Recent announcements (*a kind of news section that can be read, updated every time Internet connection is available*)
- Information pages with interlinks
- Works offline *(attendees are mostly foreign with either expensive Internet or none at all)*

Is there any open source app like this? I would use it as a base. My app will be open source.

*I was thinking about using the Google I/O 2014 app ([Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.samples.apps.iosched), [Source code](https://github.com/google/iosched)) but it requires to sign in with a Google account, which is undesirable.*

Comment: Why an app? Can't you make a mobile website? If offline usage is an issue, maybe MediaWiki + Kiwix? ;)

Comment: @Nemo: "*Why an app?*" Because it must work offline.

Comment: @Nemo: MediaWiki + Kiwix does not have a recent announcement feature.

Comment: I think it's possible to release a new version and make it automatically show in the Kiwix library, with the new incremental updates patch you could release a patch that just adds a sitenotice with important updates. :) Or just a message together with the library update, that shouldn't be too hard to make.